# How to calculate correlations pairwise in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, correlation

I have this dataset loaded in from an .csv file.

Let's say the dataframe df looks like this (made simpler for this post):

```
Run_num  trial_name  unit_1_act  unit_2_act  unit_3_act  unit_4_act     
  0          trial1       0.0      0.000000      0.272244      0.006428   
  0          trial2       0.0      0.000000      0.898450      0.000729   
  0          trial3       0.0      0.893845      0.000000      0.000000   
  0          trial4       0.0      0.879367      0.000000      0.006312   
  1          trial1       0.0      0.000000      0.324059      0.013421   
  1          trial2       0.0      0.000000      0.284394      0.004305   
  1          trial3       0.0      0.492053      0.000000      0.000504   
  1          trial4       0.0      0.540394      0.000000      0.000000   
  2          trial1       0.0      0.000000      0.430504      0.105394   
  2          trial2       0.0      0.000000      0.549384      0.004934 
  2          trial3       0.0      0.879367      0.000000      0.000312   
  2          trial4       0.0      0.394034      0.000123      0.000000
```

So, for each "run_num" there are four trial types (i.e. trial1, trial2, trial3, trial4), and each one of those trial types has a sequence of activation values of several *units*, i.e. unit_1_act, unit_2_act, etc.

I'm interested in the correlation of unit activity between trial types. I'd like to get all the pairwise correlations of the unit activities between trial1, trial2, trial3, and trial4, *for each run number separately*. So for instance, I'd want to take the sequence of values in unit_1_act through unit_4_act of trial 1 run 0, and correlate that with unit_1_act through unit_4_act of all other trials, **within the same run**. Eventually I'd take mean the across runs so I can see the overall correlation matrix of trial1 vs trial2, trial 1 vs trial3, etc.

I'm a little stumped on this. For one, the df.corr() function works on columns, and the data I want to run the correlation on is within each row (i.e unit_*_act). I could potentially reshape the dataframe so the unit activity is within a column, but I don't think that works because I need to look at correlations only within specific runs? And what is the best form of the output of all these correlations considering I'll eventually want to get the mean, standard deviation, etc across runs?

Thanks!

Comment: Some combination of `pivot_table` , dictionaries and `groupby` is possibly your way to go. I'll have lunch now, but if there's no answer when I come back, I will give it a try.

Comment: Can you show what result you expect with example data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape first you dataframe to make each trial as a column with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack).

```
print (df.set_index(['Run_num', 'trial_name']).stack().unstack(level='trial_name'))
trial_name            trial1    trial2    trial3    trial4
Run_num                                                   
0       unit_1_act  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
        unit_2_act  0.000000  0.000000  0.893845  0.879367
        unit_3_act  0.272244  0.898450  0.000000  0.000000
        unit_4_act  0.006428  0.000729  0.000000  0.006312
1       unit_1_act  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
        unit_2_act  0.000000  0.000000  0.492053  0.540394
        unit_3_act  0.324059  0.284394  0.000000  0.000000
        unit_4_act  0.013421  0.004305  0.000504  0.000000
2       unit_1_act  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
        unit_2_act  0.000000  0.000000  0.879367  0.394034
        unit_3_act  0.430504  0.549384  0.000000  0.000123
        unit_4_act  0.105394  0.004934  0.000312  0.000000
```

Then use `groupby` to do [`corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.corr.html) per run_num.

```
df_corr = df.set_index(['Run_num', 'trial_name']).stack().unstack(level='trial_name')\
           .groupby(level='Run_num').corr()
print (df_corr)
trial_name            trial1    trial2    trial3    trial4
Run_num trial_name                                        
0       trial1      1.000000  0.999765 -0.343824 -0.346886
        trial2      0.999765  1.000000 -0.333694 -0.336880
        trial3     -0.343824 -0.333694  1.000000  0.999977
        trial4     -0.346886 -0.336880  0.999977  1.000000
1       trial1      1.000000  0.999682 -0.352145 -0.351722
        trial2      0.999682  1.000000 -0.340504 -0.340060
        trial3     -0.352145 -0.340504  1.000000  1.000000
        trial4     -0.351722 -0.340060  1.000000  1.000000
2       trial1      1.000000  0.971875 -0.438267 -0.437924
        trial2      0.971875  1.000000 -0.337480 -0.337048
        trial3     -0.438267 -0.337480  1.000000  1.000000
        trial4     -0.437924 -0.337048  1.000000  1.000000
```